# Triangles' relation to Tangent

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

I saw an equation on my book which replaced $\tan (B/2)$ with $\sqrt{ s(s - b) /(s - a) (s - c) }$

How are they related?

Comment: Who are $B$, $a$, $b$, $c$ and $s$ ?

Comment: See here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Trigonometry/Solving_triangles_by_half-angle_formulae But be warned that your formula is not correct.

Comment: See a long proof of this formula in : http://output.to/sideway/default.asp?qno=130600025

Comment: I just discovered that this sort of formula has been given the name "Briggs' formulas".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you meant this:

$$ {\displaystyle \displaystyle \tan \left({\frac {B}{2}}\right)={\sin({\frac {B}{2}}) \over \cos({\frac {B}{2}})}={\sqrt {{(s-c)(s-a)} \over {s(s-b)}}}} $$

A trig ratio cannot equal area of the triangle! Please see the book carefully.